# Awk tolower a string that starts with an accent - support for foreign characters

Tags: awk, character-encoding, diacritics

I have a file with this string in a line: **"Ávila"**

And I want to get this output: **"ávila"**.

The problem is that the function **tolower** of awk only works when the string does not start with accent, and I must use awk.

For example, if I do **awk 'BEGIN { print tolower("Ávila") }'** then I get **"Ávila"** instead of **"ávila"**, that is what I expect.

But if I do **awk 'BEGIN { print tolower("Castellón") }'** then I get **"castellón"**

Comment: Using gnu awk 4.0.1 I get "ávila" from `tolower("Ávila")`.

Comment: As an aside: the problem is not related to the _position_ of the foreign character in the string (in your 2nd command the foreign letter happened to be lowercase already), but to the fundamental inability to recognize non-ASCII letters as letters in certain `awk` implementations.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For a given `awk` implementation to work properly with non-ASCII characters (foreign letters), it must respect the active locale's character encoding, as reflected in the (effective) `LC_CTYPE` setting (run `locale` to see it).

These days, most locales use UTF-8 encoding, a multi-byte-on-demand encoding that is single-byte in the ASCII range, and uses 2 to 4 bytes to represent all other Unicode characters.
Thus, for a given `awk` implementation to recognize non-ASCII (accented, foreign) letters, it must be able to recognize *multiple bytes* as a *single character*.

**Among the major `awk` implementations**,

- GNU Awk (`gawk`), the default on *some* Linux distros
- BSD `awk`, as also used on OS X
- [Mawk](http://invisible-island.net/mawk/mawk.html) (`mawk`), the default on Debian-based Linux distros such as Ubuntu

**only *GNU* Awk properly handles UTF8-encoded characters** (and presumably any other encoding if specified in the locale):

```
$ echo ÁvilA | gawk '{print tolower($0)}'
ávila  # both Á and A lowercased
```

Conversely, if you expressly want to limit character processing to ASCII only, prepend `LC_CTYPE=C`:

```
$ echo ÁvilA | LC_CTYPE=C gawk '{print tolower($0)}'
Ávila  # only ASCII char. A lowercased
```

**Practical advice:**

- To **determine what implementation your default `awk` is**, run `awk --version`.

  - In the case of Mawk you'll get an error message, because it only supports printing version information with `-W version`, but that error message will contain the word `mawk`.
- I**f possible, install and use GNU Awk** (and optionally make it the default `awk`); it is available for most Unix-like platforms; e.g.:

  - On Debian-based platforms such as Ubuntu: `sudo apt-get install gawk`
  - On OS X, using [Homebrew](http://brew.sh): `brew install gawk`.
- **If you must use either BSD Awk or Mawk, use the above `LC_CTYPE=C` approach** to **ensure that the multi-byte UTF-8 characters are at least *passed through* without modification.**<sup>[1]</sup>, but **foreign letters will NOT be recognized as letters** (and thus won't be lowercased, in this case).

---

[1] BSD Awk and Mawk on OS X (the latter curiously *not* on Linux) treat UTF-8-encoded character as follows:

- Each *byte* is mistakenly interpreted as its own *character*.
- If, *after ignoring the high bit*, the resulting byte value falls into the range of ASCII uppercase letters, `32` is added to the *original* byte value to obtain the lowercase counterpart.

In the case at hand, this means:

- `Á` is Unicode codepoint `U+00C1`, whose UTF-8 encoding is the *2-byte sequence*: `0xC3 0x81`.
- `0xC3`: Dropping the high bit (`0xC3 & 0x7F`) yields `0x43`, which is interpreted as ASCII letter `C`, and `32` (`0x20`) is therefore added to the *original value*, yielding `0xE3` (`0xC3 + 0x20`).
- `0x81`: Dropping the high bit (`0x81 & 0x7F`) yields `0x1`, which is not in the range of ASCII uppercase letters (`65-90`, `0x41-0x5a`), so the byte is left as-is.
- Effectively, the first byte is modified from `0xC3` to `0xE3`, while the 2nd byte is left untouched; since `0xC3 0x81` is *not* a properly UTF-8-encoded character, the terminal will print `?` instead to signal that.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to comment on your reply, which is correct, but I need to be able to format what I'm adding, otherwise, it becomes gibberish.

Super useful and I would like to add the following for the ones that have problems with uppercase :

```
bash-3.2$ echo "TOMÀS VICENÇ ROMÀ" |LC_CTYPE=C gawk '{ print tolower($0)}'

tomÀs vicenÇ romÀ


bash-3.2$ echo "TOMÀS VICENÇ ROMÀ" |LC_CTYPE=C gawk '{ print $0}'|tr '[:upper:]' '[:lower:]'

tomàs vicenç romà
```